# How can I get files on my iPad into my Dropbox?

Tags: ipad, dropbox

Let's say I get a file in an email, or have it stored in GoodReader, or find a link to it on the web, and want to put it into my Dropbox using the ipad app.

It seems like the only files you can add from the app are photos and video.  Am I missing anything?  Goodreader is a great example of how an app can "pull in" compatible files from emails, etc, but I can't find any similar capability in the Dropbox app.

Comment: iOS is so weird. No filesystem means you have to do the clunkiest stuff that should be so easy.

Comment: You're not missing anything. [Dropbox is missing it](http://www.dropbox.com/help/84).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that whilst this capability is not included in the official dropbox app, it is possible to accomplish using GoodReader for iPad.

1. Open GoodReader on iPad and expand the section in the bottom right of the main screen which says "Connect to Servers"
2. Tap "Add"
3. Tap "Dropbox"
4. Enter your details and click add
5. Now tap the server you just added (I called it "Dropbox")
6. In the bottom right hand corner of the popover that just came up is a button saying upload. Tap it.
7. Select the files you want to upload and tap "Upload"

You will only need to do steps 5-7 the second time

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I don't have anything in my 'My Documents' folder in Goodreader, but I'll have a go at seeing how I would get stuff into there. :-)

Comment: You can get it in via a plethora of different means: iTunes file sharing, opening from email, (tap and hold an attachment), via any webdav server, mobileMe, you name it they probably have it...

Comment: Wow.   I had NO idea.   This makes me think I need to go back and read GoodReader's docs to see what else it can do.

Comment: @robsoft, I think you all should really consider taking a look at my [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395/how-can-i-get-files-into-my-dropbox-from-my-ipad/10715#10715)! :P

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Habilis](http://www.gethabilis.com/) to email files to Dropbox. I use it to transfer photos from my phone to my iPad without needing the camera connection kit. It works like a charm.

If you have a Mac, you can also use [MobileDL](http://scottjacksonx.github.com/MobileDL/) to get files into Dropbox. It's an app that allows you to paste a URL into [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/) on your iPad/iPhone/iPod and it'll start downloading the file on your Mac. Just make sure to go into the preferences when you install it and set the downloads folder to your Dropbox. The downside, of course, is that you'll have to leave your Mac on at home so you can use it.

Comment: Habilis is "retired'

Answer (score 4):

This is actually possible to do without any extra applications now. With attachments that can be previewed in Mail, and most every file type in Safari, you can use the Open in... and choose Dropbox. You then get to choose a folder to upload the file to and tap the Upload button.

In Mail, do this:
[image: Mail screenshot]

And in Safari, do this:
[image: Safari screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I've been wanting to do this too, but thus far to no avail. From the Dropbox in-app help, it states, *'The iPad version of the Dropbox Mobile Application allows you to upload any videos or photos synced to your gallery.'*

So, from that I'd assume that you're not missing anything - your only upload options at the moment are photos and video from the general gallery. :-(

It'll be interesting to see if people post any usable workarounds, of course. :-)

Comment: Check out @Tom's GoodReader workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice solution: http://sendtodropbox.com

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/2503/upload-files-through-email-from-ipad-iphone)'s how I found it. Thanks [votebox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/category/Votebox)!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Cawas. Will have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding that link on the Web, icabmobile: http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8 can download files and upload to dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

if you have goodreader, you can add your dropbox account to it, no more need fore the dropbox app.

Answer (score -2):

Jailbreak your device and install [iFile](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/eu.heinelt.ifile) from Cydia.